# Margin Bottom 100% and Margin Top -100% not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin, gsap

I'm having trouble understanding why my third div doesn't stack at -100% height when I use margin-top. I'm animating a movement of divs using Greensock and margin-left works perfectly for the first div. But when I try to move the upper div down, it is way higher. I know that height is based on width, but as far as I understand if I use 100% it shouldn't matter what the dimensions are. I tried using margin-bottom first but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. Here is the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kqyyq78q/

```
<body>
<a id="overlay"></a>
<div id="start">
<img src="http://imgh.us/roadtest1.svg" id="road" />
</div>
<div id="num1">
<img src="http://imgh.us/roadtest2.svg" id="road" />
</div>
<div id="num2">
<img src="http://imgh.us/roadtest3.svg" id="road" />
</div>
</body>

html,
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

#overlay {
z-index: 8;
position: fixed;
margin-left: 50%;
padding-top: 20%;
}

#road {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

#start {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
}

#num1 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
margin-left: 100%;
}

#num2 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
margin-top: -100%;
}
```

Comment: What is your desired end state for this, visually? Can you provide an image?

Comment: I want the div's to be able to move as if transversing one whole image. Like on the movement from div #start to #num1, it moves smoothly. There's no issue pushing #num1 down, it's just there's a white gap when trying to move #num2 down from above. I just don't understand why there's the gap between #num1 and #num2

Comment: Here's an image example http://s30.postimg.org/m4u6hm9wx/example.jpg I'm having problems moving from 2 to 3 because there's a white space that I can't understand why it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that you're using percentages on the margin as though they were relative to the image's height.

**Percentages for margin and padding are relative to the width**. That means that your `margin-top: -100%;` rule will overshoot the mark whenever its width is not equal to its height. On the other hand, the css rule `top: -100%;` *is* based on the height, and will work.

I've altered your code a bit to show [a working example of this](https://jsfiddle.net/kqyyq78q/3/).

```
#num2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}
```